# What function instead jQuery async:false

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

In the old version of jQuery. Sometime I use jQuery ajax and set async:false to wait the response from ajax. But in present day, async:false is deprecated. I don't know how to use other instead async:false. Please suggest me.

[My code when I use jQuery ajax async:false]

```js
function check(id) {
  var check = '';
  
  jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'test.php',
    data : 'id='+id,
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    success:function(data) {
      if(data == 'good') {
        check = 'pass';
      }
      else
      if(data == 'bad') {
        check = 'not_pass';
      }
    }
  });
  
  if(check == 'pass') {
    alert('Pass');
  }
  else
  if(check == 'not_pass') {
    alert('Not pass');
  }
}
```

In above code I used async:false to wait the response from test.php.
After test.php but not async:false is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`async: false` was always meant to be used only rarely, because it blocks all user input while it's waiting for the response from the server. It's much better to handle the result asynchronously, e.g.:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'test.php',
    data : 'id='+id,
    cache:false
})
.done(function(data) {
    if (data == 'good') {
        alert('Pass');
    }
    else if (data == 'bad') {
        alert('Not pass');
    }
})
.error(function() {
    //handle the error...
});
```

Note that I'm also using the new Promises interface (the `done()` and `error()` callbacks). The `success` and `error` options still work if you prefer those.